# What is the opposite class to TcpListener in C# and how to use it to send message to server

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, tcp, client

I have programmed TCP Server in my application which can handle incoming connections and decode inoming messages.

But now I wanted create a client on Windows Phone which will send short string message: "I am Client" to the server. In server I used the `class TcpListener` so I was looking for the "opposite" class like `TcpSender` but I could not find one.

The servers ip is: `192.168.0.13` and port is `13000`.

**To sum up the question:** How to create short client which will send single message to the server?

My server looks like - I post it only to show that I've done it:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace HomeSecurity {
    class TCPEventServer {
        private TcpListener tcpListener;
        private Thread listenThread;

        public TCPEventServer() {
            this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 13000);
            this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
            this.listenThread.Start();
        }
        private void ListenForClients() {
            this.tcpListener.Start();
            while (true) {

                TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
                clientThread.Start(client);
            }
        }
        private void HandleClientComm(object client) {
            TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
            NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            byte[] message = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;

            while (true) {
                bytesRead = 0;
                try {

                    bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
                } catch {

                    break;
                }
                if (bytesRead == 0) {

                    break;
                }

                ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();

                string messageDecoded = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);
                messageDecoded = messageDecoded.Replace("\r", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty);
                string ip = ((IPEndPoint)tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address + "";

                Console.WriteLine("message: " + messageDecoded + " ip: " + ip);

                VideoStream.PassMessage(messageDecoded, ip);
            }

            tcpClient.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `TcpSender`, you have to use [`TcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) to send data.

Comment: @Sinatr This class seems to be unavailable in Windows Phone.

Comment: Once you know what you need, rest is assured -> google "tcpclient wp8" -> [first result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the TcpClient class [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) That has functions for establishing a connection to a listener, with example code.

Comment: This class seems to be unavailable in Windows Phone.

Comment: ah, wasn't aware of that. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858(v=vs.105).aspx) instead then. :)

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use SocketEx but I get: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603010/when-i-want-to-use-nuget-library-socketex-tcpclient-dll-cannot-find-or-open-t