# When I want to use nuget SocketEx: FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, nuget

I wanted to use `Socketex.tcpclient` from a nuGet library.
I added it this way:
[image]

When I want to use it in application

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using SocketEx;
using System.Threading;
namespace HomeSecurityClient {
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage {
        private string localIP, globalIP, port;
        private Thread sendThread;
        public MainPage() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            String args = null;
            NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("ms_nfp_launchargs", out args);
            if (args != null) {
                MessageBox.Show(args);
                string[] splittedArgs = args.Split(' ');
                globalIP = splittedArgs[0];
                port = splittedArgs[1];
                localIP = splittedArgs[2];
                makeSwitch();
                sendThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(makeSwitch));
                sendThread.Start();
            }
        }

        private void makeSwitch() {         
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(localIP, Int32.Parse(port));//THIS CAUSES THIS MESSAGE
      //      client.Connect(localIP, Int32.Parse(port));
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Just after I accept message box and method `makeSwitch` is invoked I get:**

```
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{39989B95-A54A-4810-B4EE-35B33265A680}\Install\socketex.tcpclient.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
param=89.77.153.205
13000
192.168.0.13
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.Net.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.Net.ni.dll
param=89.77.153.205
13000
192.168.0.13
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.Net.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.Net.ni.dll
The thread 0x38 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
```

**How to fix that?**

Comment: First chance exceptions aren't something you need to worry about. it's telling you that an exception happened. If it doesn't bubble up to your code, it's being handled. [See here for more info](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx)

Comment: Nothing appears to be going wrong, these are just debugger notifications.  The library is a bit sloppy, using exceptions for flow control instead of something exceptional, that's all.  Not an uncommon problem if you rely on the code written by somebody else of course.